# Como debo actualizar el DataGrid en WPF C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid, linq-to-sql

Hola estimad@s estoy aprendiendo c# y empecé creando un CRUD. En la ventana principal esta el DataGrid y en una ventana secundaria el formulario para ingresar un nuevo registro. El problema está cuando inserto el registro se guarda exitosamente en la tabla de bbdd pero no se refleja el cambio en el DataGrid. Cuando reinicio la aplicación recién aprece el nuevo registro agregado.

**Ventana Principal**

```
namespace RegistroDeEstudiantes
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        Conexion connect;
        
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            String conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistroDeEstudiantes.Properties.Settings.ColegioConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            contextOrm = new ormLinqDataContext(conexion);

            MostrarEstudiantes();

        }

        private void Crear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AgregarEstudiante WindowsAddStudend = new AgregarEstudiante();

            WindowsAddStudend.ShowDialog();
        }


        private void MostrarEstudiantes()
        {

            TablaEstudiantes.ItemsSource = contextOrm.Estudiante;
     
        }

 
        private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TablaEstudiantes.ItemsSource = contextOrm.Estudiante;

            TablaEstudiantes.Items.Refresh();

            Console.WriteLine("Evento cargar");

        }


        public ormLinqDataContext contextOrm;

        private void Update_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TablaEstudiantes.ItemsSource = null;

            TablaEstudiantes.ItemsSource = contextOrm.Estudiante;

            TablaEstudiantes.Items.Refresh();

            Console.WriteLine("Deberia actualizar");
        }
    }

}
```

En la ventana principal e colocado el DataGrid - Y estoy usando el "evento"         Activated="Window_Activated" para mostrar todos los registros en el DataGrid

```
<DataGrid Name="TablaEstudiantes"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Background="#334155" HeadersVisibility="Column" Foreground="White" RowBackground="#FF334155" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="Extended" ColumnHeaderHeight="30" RowHeight="25" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" ForceCursor="True" IsReadOnly="True">

                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e293b" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

                <DataGrid.Columns >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Nombres" Width="180">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Nombres}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Apellidos" Width="180">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Apellidos}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edad" Width="90">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="center" Text="{Binding edad}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Carrera" Width="204">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding carrera}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Semestre" Width="120">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding semestre}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

**Ventana de Registro**

```
namespace RegistroDeEstudiantes
{

    public partial class AgregarEstudiante : Window
    {
        public AgregarEstudiante()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            String conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistroDeEstudiantes.Properties.Settings.ColegioConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            contextOrm = new ormLinqDataContext(conexion);

        }

        private void agregar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Estudiante dEstudiante = new Estudiante();

            dEstudiante.Nombres = tbNombres.Text;
            dEstudiante.Apellidos = tbApellidos.Text;
            dEstudiante.edad = Int32.Parse(tbEdad.Text);
            dEstudiante.carrera = tbCarrera.Text;
            dEstudiante.semestre = tbSemestre.Text;

            contextOrm.Estudiante.InsertOnSubmit(dEstudiante);
            contextOrm.SubmitChanges();

            this.Close();
            
        }

        ormLinqDataContext contextOrm;

    }
}
```

En la segunda ventana solo tengo con campos para registrar el nuevo estudiante
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Lo que espero conseguir es* Cuando llene los datos de registro y presione el boton de "agregar estudiante" se guarde en la bbdd y se refleje el nuevo items en el datagrid.

Espero haberme expresado correctamente, cuento con su ayuda.

Comment: Lo mejor sería usar DataBinding que gestiona toda la actualizacion por ti,. Pero en este caso, puedes probar con `TablaEstudiantes.Items.Refresh();` o bien anular el itemssource y volver a asignarlo.

Comment: Ya hice TablaEstudiantes.Items.Refresh(); pero aún así no se  muestra los nuevos datos agregados. Como haría el DataBinding?